# Install second Ubuntu distribution on second drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 13.10 already installed on `/dev/sda`. Now I want to install version 14.04 on `/dev/sdb` (screenshots from GParted are pasted below).

How should I proceed?

[image: sda]

[image: sdb]

Answer (score 2):

Just boot off a liveUSB or liveDVD, choose install, then something else option and then choose the correct drive where you want to install 14.04. Create a partition for Ubuntu, mount point \ and a swap partition (at least the size of your RAM, better 2xRAM).

Keep the boot loader on the disk where 13.10 is installed. It should detect the second Ubuntu instance and add it to the Grub menu.

Comment: I install boot loader on `/dev/sda` as you suggested, but when restart it fails with `error: no such device` and entering `grup rescue>`